# MongoDB Aggregation: Difficulty Counting Associated Items Using $lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm currently working on a MongoDB project, and I'm having trouble with a specific aggregation pipeline. I have two collections, "devices" and "variables".

I'm attempting to count the number of variables associated with a device using the `$lookup` stage. However, I'm not getting the expected results.

Here is my db schema :-

**Devices Collection:-**

```
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("..."),
      "deviceName": "Datasource Name",
    }
```

**Variables Collection :-**

```
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("..."),
      "name": "Variable Name",
      "deviceId":ObjectId("...")  //Reference to the device
    }
```

**Documents inserted in the collections :-**

**Devices:-**

```
    {
      "_id": "65a6235d484c162c28865db4",
      "deviceName": "A"
    }
```

**Variables:-**

```
[
    {
      "_id": "65a64af22cc01aa7c8474029",
      "deviceId": ObjectId("65a6235d484c162c28865db4")
      "name": "current"
    } ,
    
    {
      "_id": "65a64adb2cc01aa7c8474028",
      "deviceId": ObjectId("65a6235d484c162c28865db4")
      "name": "temp"
    } 
]
```

**I have a MongoDB aggregation pipeline that looks like this:**

```
    [
      {
        $match: {
          _id: ObjectId('65a6235d484c162c28865db4')
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'variables',
          localField: '_id',
          foreignField: 'deviceId',
          as: 'deviceVariables'
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          name: 1,
          deviceVariables: { $size: '$deviceVariables' }
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Expected output :**

I expect the aggregation pipeline to return a document with the device information and the count of associated variables along with its names.

Any guidance or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: **1.** Provide examples of documents in each instead of just the schemas. **2.** Your pipeline appears to be working as expected - [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FcAi43-NStJ)

Comment: Added it in the question itself

Comment: Your `_id` is string or objectId

Comment: ObjectId not string @TanThien

Comment: Answered below. Also, this is why examples are important. Your _schema_ for `devices` has the fields `{ "_id", "name", "description" }` but your example has `{ "_id", "deviceName" }`. Affects the `project` stage at the end, where `name` means nothing.

Comment: Thanks for bringing it to my notice. I changed it @aneroid but still it is not working

Answer (score 2):

> *I expect the aggregation pipeline to return a document with the device information and the count of associated variables along with its names.*

I would *guess* that you want the names of all the variables, which is the only part missing in your `$project` stage. Add them with `$concatArrays`:

```js
db.devices.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId("65a6235d484c162c28865db4") } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "variables",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "deviceId",
      as: "deviceVariables"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      deviceVariables: { $size: "$deviceVariables" },
      deviceVariableNames: { $concatArrays: "$deviceVariables.name" }  // only added this
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yDgWlyiIi8-)

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("65a6235d484c162c28865db4"),
    "deviceVariableNames": [
      "current",
      "temp"
    ],
    "deviceVariables": 2,
    "name": "A"
  }
]
```

Comment: When I run the same in MongoDB Compass, it shows that the pipeline generated no results, but it works on the Mongo Playground

Comment: @anonymous_33008899 That's a completely separate problem. What version of Mongo are you on? It works on Mongo Playground 6.0.12 and Mongo 7.0.4 locally.

Comment: Running db.version() says it is 6.0.6 Mongo version

Comment: @anonymous_33008899 Try replacing the `$project` with `$set` to see if the fields do get set or not. Otherwise, I suspect there are differences between the fields in your example data and your actual data. You'll need to resolve that yourself or show a [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) example with the "not working" result. Nothing anyone else can do. Check the [release notes for 6.0](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/6.0/#std-label-release-notes-6.0) to see if any related bug was fixed after 6.0.6.